# For which $n$ does a y-formed $n$-polyomino tile a $n \times n \times n$-cube?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, recreational-mathematics, tiling

I got from my children as a gift a puzzle consisting of 25 y-shaped 5-polyominoes that form a $5 \times 5 \times 5$-cube (see picture).

I'm wondering for which $n$ does a y-formed $n$-polyomino tile a $n \times n \times n$-cube?

By a y-formed $n$-polyomino I understand a generalisation of the y-formed $5$-polyomino (made of the $5$ squares $(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (1, 1)$), i.e., the center of the $n$ squares can be chosen as $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), \dotsc, (n-2,0)$. The polyomino has a thickness of 1.

For $n=5$ I have the (wooden) proof that it's possible before me, for $n=4$ it's trivial (as one can tile one $4 \times 4 \times 1$-slice of the $4 \times 4 \times 4$-cube already with four y-formed $4$-polyominoes), what about $n=6, 7 , \dotsc$?

Any ideas for patterns that work for whole sequences of $n$, any proofs that for some $n$ it's not possible?

[image: A 5×5×5-cube tiled by 25 y-shaped 5-polyominoes]

Comment: Using Don Knuth's [implementation](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs/dlx1.w) of Algorithm X, I've verified that there are no solutions for $n=6$ and $n=7$. Also, Michael Reid has a [webpage](https://www.cflmath.com/Polyomino/boxes.html) with many ways of packing various polycubes into boxes.

Comment: I did not know what a y-shaped polyomino was except from the picture, so I have edited in a description in words, which is  hopefully correct.  I am confused by the reference to the centre of the squares.  Do you mean to say that the generalised polyomino has the squares $(0, 0), (1, 0), \dotsc, (n - 2, 0), (i, 1)$ for some integer $i$ with $0 \le i < n - 1$?

Comment: @LSpice I believe that the question was unambiguously stated. Also, in your notation, I guess the OP wants $i=1$. In fact I'm afraid that your edit, in particular the phrase "... can be any of $(0,0)$, ...", obscured the formulation.

Comment: @PeterMueller, I think that the question cannot have been fully unambiguously stated, since it said that a y-formed $n$-polyomino was like a y-formed $5$-polynomino without saying what the latter was—I didn't know without a picture.  That was the point of my edit, and I hope it can be kept in subsequent edits, if needed (except my typo $n$ for $5$, which I fixed).  I'm not sure what the difference between "can be chosen as $(0,0), (1,0),\dotsc, (n - 2,0)$" and "can be any of $(0,0), (1,0), \dotsc, (n - 2,0)$" is, but, since you say it is confusing, I reverted it.

Comment: My interpretation was: a y-formed $n$-polyomino is given by the $n-1$ cells $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, …, $(n-2,0)$, together with the cell $(1,1)$.

Comment: I certainly have no objection to [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438497/for-which-n-does-a-y-formed-n-polyomino-tile-a-n-times-n-times-n-cube#comment1133413_438497) formulation, if it is what was intended!  However, then I didn't know how to make sense of the terminology "the center of the squares can be chosen as $(0, 0), (1, 0), \dotsc, (n - 2, 0)$"; what is the choice that is being made?  (That is, what is the ‘centre’?)  Anyway, all I wanted is to make sure I understood the statement.

Comment: Many thanks for improving my formulation, and sorry that my original one was not crystal clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no solutions for $n\ge6$. For $n=6$ one checks that the exact cover formulation of the problem has no solution, as ho boon suan did in the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438497/for-which-n-does-a-y-formed-n-polyomino-tile-a-n-times-n-times-n-cube#comment1133051_438497).

For $n\ge7$, the following argument works: Let $(i,j,k)$ for $1\le i,j,k\le n$ be the $n^3$ positions of the cube to be covered. Consider the subset $S$ of positions $(i,j,k)$ where $i,j,k\in\{1, 4, n\}$. Each polyomino intersects $S$ in either $0$ or $2$ positions. As $\lvert S\rvert=27$ is odd, there is no cover.

There are also choices of $S$ which are symmetric under the symmetries of the cube:

If $n$ is odd, then for $S=\{(i,j,k)\;|\;i,j,k\in\{1,(n+1)/2,n\}\}$ we get $\lvert S\rvert=27$, while $\lvert S\cap P\rvert=0$ or $2$ for each polyomino.

If $n$ is even, then for $S=\{(i,j,k)\;|\;i,j,k\in\{1,n/2,n/2+1,n\}\}$ we get $\lvert S\rvert=64$, while $\lvert S\cap P\rvert=0$ or $3$ for each polyomino.

Comment: This makes rough sense to me, but I think I'm having a little bit of trouble visualizing: what in the argument needs $n\geq7$?

Comment: Thinking of the y-polyomino as a straight line of $n-1$ cubes, say along the $x$-axis, together with an extra protruding cube, that cube can only have $x$-coordinates in $\{2,3,n-2,n-1\}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki To complement ho boon suan's comment: If $n=6$ then $n−2=4$, so it can happen that the polyomino hits S (in its "extra protruding cube") in only one point.

Comment: @PeterMueller Thank you! That's exactly the bit that I was missing.